# Dealing with implementations for several platforms

Tags: objective-c, macos, cross-platform, bazel

I'm trying to build a cross-platform library which uses the several platform's API's. I'm doing macOS right now and I've come into a problem as I need to use objective-c.

I have this:

```
cc_library(
    name = "base",
    hdrs = ["application.h"],
    deps = [":base_mac"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

objc_library(
    name = "base_mac",
    srcs = ["application_mac.mm"],
)
```

In other packages, I'm depending on `base`.

The problem is that `application_mac.mm` includes `application.h` and implements it but it doesn't compile because the `base_mac` rule doesn't depend on the `base` rule and can't use its headers. It also doesn't work to add this dependency as then we have a dependency cycle and bazel doesn't like it.

So, how do I best solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

- either add `hdrs = ["application.h"]` to `base_mac` too, or
- create another `cc_library` with just `hdrs = ["application.h"]`, depend on that from both `base` and `base_mac`, and remove the `hdrs` from `base` and `base_mac`

Comment: Thanks, I ended up following your second suggestion.